# Bootstrap navbar dropdown inside of navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on a site and I started off with the dashboard example from the Bootstrap website. However, when I added in a dropdown to the navbar, it stays inside the navbar and breaks the whole thing. I can't figure out the style that is causing this problem. The code seems a bit too much to paste here, so I put it into Codepen:
https://codepen.io/andersmmg/pen/wOgmby

Here's the css it adds to make the dashboard style work properly:

```
body {
  font-size: .875rem;
}

.feather {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

/*
 * Sidebar
 */

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100; /* Behind the navbar */
  padding: 48px 0 0; /* Height of navbar */
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.sidebar-sticky {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 48px);
  padding-top: .5rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
}

@supports ((position: -webkit-sticky) or (position: sticky)) {
  .sidebar-sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
  }
}

.sidebar .nav-link {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333;
}

.sidebar .nav-link .feather {
  margin-right: 4px;
  color: #999;
}

.sidebar .nav-link.active {
  color: #007bff;
}

.sidebar .nav-link:hover .feather,
.sidebar .nav-link.active .feather {
  color: inherit;
}

.sidebar-heading {
  font-size: .75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*
 * Content
 */

[role="main"] {
  padding-top: 48px; /* Space for fixed navbar */
}

/*
 * Navbar
 */

.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.navbar .form-control {
  padding: .75rem 1rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar .form-control::placeholder {
    color: white;
}

.navbar .form-control:focus::placeholder {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
}

.form-control-dark {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.form-control-dark:focus {
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just removed the code you had for the drop down menu and replaced it with the code example from the documentation and the drop menu now functions correctly. I think some of your code was not allowing the drop down to exist outside of its container which was causing its parent container to expand (namely the `ul` and `li` elements)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
  <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="index.php">Store Manager</a>
  <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <div class="dropdown dropleft">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      andersmmg
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You will still need to style the button to the colors you want but the functionality is there. I changed the menu to show on the left side (`dropleft`) so it would not run off the page. You can see my [Fiddle of working solution here](https://jsfiddle.net/crazymatt/k0Lyp7vb/3/). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you see bootstrap gives in your element style:

```
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
}
```

That's overrides also bootstrap class

```
    .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute;
}
```

I don't know if this is the best solution, but you can achieve it with this:

```
.dropdown-menu.show {
    position: absolute;
    left: -60px;
}
```

I hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Go through this pen to check the answer
[codepen](https://codepen.io/nani554/pen/RdKBja) for solution
1) i just made ul position absolute and gave some grid layout for alignment purpose.

```
.navbar-nav {
 position: absolute;
 left: 85%;
}
```